# I am having problems trying to toggle an icon in javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to toggle my edit button to the class of hidden and my trash button to the class of show. but I am not able to target the elements I always am getting the error of NULL would anyone be able to help I am stuck.

I have tried many ways but I cant get the edit button to toggle to display none and my trash button to toggle to display flex thanks guys for any help

HTML
```


TO-DO LIST




Today's To Do

````
  <div class="todo-list"></div>
  <button id="clear-btn" class="clear-btn" type="button" 
     name="button">
    Clear all completed
    </button>
    </div>
   </body>
  </html>
   ```
````

```js
const clear = document.querySelector(".clear-btn");
const list = document.querySelector(".todo-list");
const input = document.getElementById("add-input");
const form = document.getElementById("todoform");

let todos = [];
const LINE_THROUGH = "lineThrough";

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  saveTodo();
});

function saveTodo() {
  const todoValue = input.value;

  todos.push({
    value: todoValue,
    completed: false,
  });
  input.value = "";
  renderTodos();
}

function renderTodos() {
  list.innerHTML = "";

  todos.forEach((todo, index) => {

    list.innerHTML += `
    <div class="todo" id=${index}>
   
    <i class="fa ${
      todo.checked ? "solid fa-check" : "regular fa-square"
    }"  data-action="check"
    ></i>
   
    <p class=${todo.checked ? LINE_THROUGH : ""}  data- 
    action="check">${todo.value}</p>
   
    
    
    <span class= "edit">
    <i class='fas fa-ellipsis-v edit-task  '   data-action="edit">
    </i>
    </span>
 
    <i class="fa-solid fa-trash-can trash-btnn hidden " data- 
    action="delete">
    
    </i>

    </div>

    `;
  });
}

list.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  const { target } = event;
  const parentElement = target.parentNode;
  if (parentElement.className !== "todo") return;

  const todo = parentElement;
  const todoId = Number(todo.id);

  const { action } = target.dataset;

  action === "check" && checkTodo(todoId);
  // action === 'edit' && checkTodo(todoId);
  // action === 'delete' && checkTodo(todoId);
});

function checkTodo(todoId) {
  todos = todos.map((todo, index) => ({
    ...todo,
    checked: index === todoId ? !todo.checked : todo.checked,
  }));

  renderTodos();
}
const threeVBtn = document.querySelector(".edit-task");
const trashBtn = document.querySelector(".trash-btnn");

threeVBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  trashBtn.classList.toggle("show");
  threeVBtn.classList.toggle("hidden");
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.trash-btnn {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgb(204, 16, 47);
}

.show {
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Does your script run before the DOM is loaded?

Comment: Can you try formatting your code to make it more readable, indentation is off and that might be why the code blocks are on and off. Also, comments like "help me I'm stuck" shouldn't be included in questions - it's just [the style](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on here. Edit: the language specifier should come after the three back ticks, on the same line, to open the code block

Comment: Can you share the whole file of JS code and how it is attached to the  HTML?

Comment: hi a2k42 ok I will and ok I will share all of the js code

Comment: Are you selecting DOM elements before you add them?

Comment: i updated all of js code

Comment: i get the error  Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')

Comment: Yes, but what line of code is giving you that error? It is quite common to see this if your JS is loaded, and run, before all the HTML is loaded.

Comment: Please, share the  HTML/Markup. I requested it earlier as well.

Comment: i am getting the error on line 90 at  threeVBtn.addEventListener

Comment: ok i will add the html

Comment: You haven't linked the stylesheet and the  JS file in your HTML,  how does work?  or have you left them out here on purpose?

Comment: hey it is because I am using webpack so they are loaded

Comment: Okay, I assumed so too.

Answer (score 0):

It is because on your first render there is no todo initially and the element specified by querySelector for `threeVBtn` returns undefined. One simple way is to check if the element is added to document before attaching event listener, like this:

```
if (threeVBtn) {
  threeVBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    trashBtn.classList.toggle("show");
    threeVBtn.classList.toggle("hidden");
  });
//perform any action for  once threeVBtn is added to Document
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you run any of the DOM selection methods (`querySelector`, `getElementByClassName`, etc), it only grabs what's currently in the DOM (ie. currently rendered html). When you add or remove items from the DOM, you must re-select elements to get the current items. It's kind of a pain, but there is a solution.

There is a concept called "event delegation" which is a technique that solves this problem. Delegation works by picking a parent element of the dynamic list - it can be any parent element so long as the element stays in the DOM while your list is dynamically changing. Many people just use the `<body>` since it's always guaranteed to be there. Whenever something *inside* the parent element is clicked, the event does this cool thing called "bubbling" - which is beyond the scope of this answer. You can read all about [DOM events, bubbling, and delegation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events).

You can attach your click handlers to the `<body>` element and check the `event.target` for the different types of things you want, best shown by example:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
  const el = event.target;
  if (el.classList.contains("edit-task")) {
    // edit button was clicked
    ev.preventDefault();
    return;
  }

  if (el.classList.contains("trash-btnn")) {
    // trash button was clicked
    ev.preventDefault();
    return;
  }
});
```

Comment: Isn't that just a big spin around OP's implementation? but definitely, a more efficient way to add listeners consistently.

Comment: I explained the problem and the fact that they have to reselect any time the DOM changes. If they want to write the reselection code, they can. I just wanted to offer an additional/better solution overall. My solution only requires that they move existing code into a single event handler - it's not a big spin at all IMO.

Comment: I think if not for OP's betterment, your answer provides a better approach to the problem and value to the community i.e people that'll come here to read the answer who have a similar question. I found it insightful, so you have at least 1 grateful community member. 

-Cheers

Comment: thanks the event listener is now working. I still have the problem with NULL when i try to remove classes but i am now working on that

Comment: If my post helped solve your problem, it's customary to accept it as the answer. This helps other community members know that it actually worked. Thanks!